# $_GET not woking here?

Tags: php, html

get does not working in this code 
I tried this one and have

> Notice: Undefined index: charttype

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php" name="charttype">
  <select name="charttype" id="charttype" class="custom-select" value="charttype">
    <option selected value="0">Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Pie Chart</option>
    <option value="2">Scatter Chart</option>
    <option value="3">Bar Chart</option>
    <option value="4">Line Chart</option>
  </select>
</form>

<?php 

$chart_type = "";
$chart_type = $_GET['charttype'];  
?>
```

Comment: Until your form is submitted in some way - there may not be any `$_GET` or `$_POST` values.  You should always either check if the value exists or that a 'submit' button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the `POST` request inside the form tag, you can not access it by using `$_GET`

```
 <form method="POST" action="index.php" name="charttype">
```

to get both `$_GET` & `$_POST` use `$_REQUEST`

```
if($_POST){
    $chart_type = $_POST['charttype'];
}
```

Change your code to following

```
<form method="GET" action="" name="charttype">
  <select name="charttype" id="charttype" class="custom-select" value="charttype">
    <option selected value="0">Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Pie Chart</option>
    <option value="2">Scatter Chart</option>
    <option value="3">Bar Chart</option>
    <option value="4">Line Chart</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  echo $chart_type = $_GET['charttype'];
 }     
?>
```

Comment: <form method="GET" action="index.php" name="charttype">  it does not work also

Comment: @AbdullahALHabib this is because  each time you are overriding the variable `$chart_type = "";` with null value

Comment: @AbdullahALHabib i have updated the code.

Comment: it didn`t woks bro i test it here and the button didn`t work because the variable not initialized  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="window.location.href='/statistics.php?charttype=<?php echo $chart_type ?>'" >Generate</button>

Comment: @AbdullahALHabib the code has been modified again, Tested and working on PHP7.0